# Installing linux on raspberry pi 3 without using it directly

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

So I searched for how to install a linux and use it on a raspberry pi 3 A+ but the only things I can find is how to install it while connected to it directly.

What I want to do is to install the linux on a micro sd card, make all the relevant settings (like ssh, networking, etc.) and then put it in the pi, power the pi and then connect to it via ssh.

The reason for this is because I don't have a spare monitor/kb (I don't have a hdmi monitor or cable, or vga>hdmi adapter).

I wanted to install a centos7 minimal on the sd card, set up my user, ssh options, etc. and then just put the sd card in the pi and be able to connect to it.

Comment: That's the regular way raspberrypi recommends installing, write an image to an SD card, then put it in a raspberry pi & boot. I think you could just mount & edit a few config files on the card before booting it, or perhaps boot it in a VM, but haven't tried it

Comment: *"I don't have a spare monitor/kb"* -- Then learn how to use a serial console.  See https://superuser.com/questions/440857/how-can-i-access-my-mini-pc-raspberrypi-mk802-mele-a1000-via-apc-via-eth/441068#441068