# No space on BeagleBone Black and need to reset it but don’t know how to

Tags: beaglebone

Me and my team have to use BeagleBone Black for a project.

We followed the basic steps, accessed the SSH terminal and it worked normally. We had to install pip and Python 3, but we couldn't, it took too long and we gave up on the day.

The next day, we were unable to access the Cloud IDE, which is reporting lack of space on the device, as well as the SSH terminal. We went wrong somewhere, but I have no idea where, since we have 4GB flash and 8GB on microSD.

I think we have to reset the BeagleBone Black flash to factory settings, but I don't know how to do it, besides updating the microSD ISO to the latest version. So if you can help me with some questions, I would be very grateful:

1. Is it possible to reset the BeagleBone Black flash? If so, how?
2. Debian is in SD, no? And the other tools too? If not, how do I know what goes to flash and what goes to SD? My SD is corrupted, I will recover it, hence the reason for the issue, I can not open it completely (but it worked with it corrupted).

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: *"accessed the SSH terminal"* -- You need to learn how to connect and use a serial console, which will provide a boot log and inform of what you of system status.  See https://superuser.com/questions/440857/how-can-i-access-my-mini-pc-raspberrypi-mk802-mele-a1000-via-apc-via-eth/441068#441068